# How does Spring Kafka handle acknowledgements when buffering messages in memory before sending batches?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Spring kafka - acknowledgement received when producing

In spring kafka and in kafka in general , there is a concept of ack.
ack = 0, 1 or all.
Depending on the flag , you should be getting acknowledgement after your message is received by the brokers and replicated.

But in spring Kafka, i was looking at the code and it seems the messages are buffered in the memory first and then sent altogether as batches.

And the kafka template gets a response after the memory is buffered .

If that is the case then how is the acknowledgement between the replicating partitions coming into picture , if the template is getting a response before the message is sent to the broker.

And if these messages are being stored in memory before being sent to the server.
What happens if the application crashes before the buffer is emptied onto the broker?

Answer (score 0):

If the application malfunctions or terminates prior to the buffered messages being transmitted to the broker, the messages stored in the buffer will be forfeited. The Kafka producer does not store the messages on disk prior to dispatching them to the broker. As a result, any messages that have not been dispatched to the broker and acknowledged will be lost in the event of a malfunction.

To enhance fault tolerance and resilience, you can customize the Kafka producer to utilize the "acks=all" setting, which guarantees that all synchronized replicas have acknowledged the write before regarding the message as sent. This setting offers an elevated degree of message endurance.

Comment: Even if the acks flag is set to all...
the concept of the producer should be same , right?
The message should be saved to the buffer [RecordAccumulator]
According to my understanding , the messages are sent to the broker by a separate sender thread.